# TableViewの背景色がセルの行の間に所々線状に見えるのですが原因がわかりません。実機でのみ現れます。

Tags: swift

お世話になります。

TableViewの背景色がセルの行の間に所々線状に見えるのですが原因がわかりません。
（画像中のグレーのライン）

シュミレーターでは現れず、実機で現れます。

行の高さを少数点のある細かな数値に設定しているためなのかとも思いますが、

線を表示させないようにする方法は何かありませんか？

[image: TableViewの背景色がセルの行の間に所々線状に見えるのですが原因がわかりません。]

Comment: 行の高さが0.5の整数倍になっていないと行間に隙間ができるのは見たことがあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認してみます。